# How to add a timeout to method start_consuming() on pika library

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I have a `BlockingConnection`, and I follow [the examples](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html) of pika documentation. But in all of them, the example of code to start consuming messages are:

```py
connection = pika.BlockingConnection()
channel = connection.channel()
channel.basic_consume('test', on_message)
try:
    channel.start_consuming()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    channel.stop_consuming()
connection.close()
```

(with more or less details).

I have to code many scripts, and I want to run one after another (for test/research purposes). But the above code require that I added ^C in each one.

I try to add some timeouts [explained in the documentation](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/parameters.html#connectionparameters), but I haven't luck. For example, if I find a parameter for set if client don't consuming any message in the last X seconds, then script finish. Is this posible in pika lib? or I have to change the approach?

Comment: You want your code to automatically kill the consumer after a certain amount of time. Is that right?

Comment: @bumblebee Ok, thats could be an option. But this "amount of time" should be after don't exists more message in the queue. For Example, in C++ client [you can to set a timeout](https://github.com/alanxz/SimpleAmqpClient#using-the-library).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `start_consuming` if you don't want your code to block. Either use `SelectConnection` or [this method](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/blocking_consumer_generator.html) that uses `consume`. You can add a timeout to the parameters passed to `consume`.

Answer (score 1):

It's too late but perhaps someone gets benefited from that. You can use `blocked_connection_timeout` argument in `pika.ConnectionParameters()` as follows,

```
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
          pika.ConnectionParameters(
            heartbeat=600,
            blocked_connection_timeout=600,
            host=self.queue_host,
            port=constants.RABBTIMQ_PORT,
            virtual_host=self.rabbitmq_virtual_host,
            credentials=pika.PlainCredentials(
              username=self.rabbitmq_username,
              password=self.rabbitmq_password
            )
          )
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pika

parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(host="localhost")
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
channel = connection.channel()

def ack_message(channel, method):
    """Note that `channel` must be the same pika channel instance via which
    the message being ACKed was retrieved (AMQP protocol constraint).
    """
    if channel.is_open:
        channel.basic_ack(method.delivery_tag)
    else:
        # Channel is already closed, so we can't ACK this message;
        # log and/or do something that makes sense for your app in this case.
        pass

def callback(channel,method, properties, body):
    ack_message(channel,method)
    print("body",body, flush=True)

channel.basic_consume(
    queue="hello", on_message_callback=callback)

channel.start_consuming()
connection.close()
```

I the original code is the answer of Luke Bakken.
But I have edited the code a lil bit.
:)